openLDAP add email alias list
Please advise - I am in the process of trying to add following below (taken from old ldap server) to a new server (OpenLDAP | TurnKey GNU/Linux) , I am also new to LDAP as well.
dn: cn=synopsys,ou=Mail Aliases,dc=sysadmin,dc=hpc,dc=co,dc=uk
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: mailGroup
objectClass: top
cn: synopsys
description: Mail alias for Synopsys
mail: synopsys@sysadmin.hpc.co.uk
member: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=sysadmin,dc=hpc,dc=co,dc=uk
member: uid=user2,ou=people,dc=sysadmin,dc=hpc,dc=co,dc=uk
mgtpRFC822MailMember: user1@sysadmin.hpc.co.uk
mgtpRFC822MailMember: user2@sysadmin.hpc.co.uk
owner: uid=michael,ou=People,dc=sysadmin,dc=hpc,dc=co,dc=uk

I am not getting much luck and tried to create schema etc for groupOfNames etc and still unable to add this.
Please advise.
Michael

Do you have both groupOfNames and mailGroup in your schema? The former is probably present by default, but the latter looks somewhat nonstandard.

i seemed to have got over the initial problem but unable to have attribute mail: synopsys@sysadmin.hpc.co.uk and get this error  'ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
additional info: attribute 'email' not allowed
'

dn: cn=customMailGroup,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: customMailGroup
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.2.1.1 NAME 'mgrpRFC822MailMember' DESC 'Mail Group RFC822 Mail Member' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{256} )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.12344556.1.1.1 NAME 'MailGroup' DESC 'Mail Group' SUP groupOfNames STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ member ) MAY ( description $ owner $ mail $ mgrpRFC822MailMember ) )

above seemed to have fixed all the issues i have.
